# Add remove partial view dynamically Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I meant to use partial views in the past but never did. Now I do have a need but for some reasons I cannot get it right. I build a noddy project

- 2 Partial Views
- Add and remove each partial views.

Problem.
I seem to be able to Add/remove View first time ,second time round I cant.
I guess I am missing something but not sure what?
I cannot seem to be able to add "x:Name" in code.

Any suggstions?
thanks

Xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyStacklayout" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Button x:Name="AddViewOne" Clicked="AddViewOne_OnClicked" Text="Add View One"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="AddViewTwo" Clicked="AddViewTwo_OnClicked" Text="Add View Two"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="RemoveViewOne" Clicked="RemoveViewOne_OnClicked" Text="Remove View One"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="RemoveViewTwo" Clicked="RemoveViewTwo_OnClicked" Text="Remove View Two"></Button>


    <views:PartialViewOne x:Name="ViewOne" mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference self}" />
    <views:PartialViewTwo x:Name="ViewTwo" mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference self}" />
</StackLayout>
```

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddViewOne_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myView = new PartialViewOne();
        ViewModelLocator.SetAutowirePartialView(myView, this);
        MyStacklayout.Children.Add(myView);
    }

    private void AddViewTwo_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PartialViewTwo myView = new PartialViewTwo();

        ViewModelLocator.SetAutowirePartialView(myView, this);
        MyStacklayout.Children.Add(myView);
    }

    private void RemoveViewOne_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var viewOneParent = (ViewOne.Parent as Layout<View>);
        viewOneParent?.Children.Remove(ViewOne);
    }
    private void RemoveViewTwo_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var viewOneParent = (ViewTwo.Parent as Layout<View>);
        viewOneParent?.Children.Remove(ViewTwo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest...simply hide and show your view one / two...Instead of adding / removing from parent (stacklayout)....By default just set IsVisible property to false...and on button click update IsVisible property

Comment: @HamidShaikh thanks for your reply. I have done something similar I have added and removed from Stacklayout.Children in code.